# How to disable a collider when the trigger of another collider has been entered?

Tags: triggers, unity-game-engine, unityscript, destroy

I am building a game where the player runs on a path. When the player triggers a collider, 2 enemy objects will spawn.

What I want is when the first collider trigger has been entered, I want the second collider, which is at a certain distance from the first collider, to get disabled for a certain time. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to disable the colliders so they won't hit or rebound off the wall, for example, then you can change your collider's "isTrigger" variable to true, to change it into a trigger volume instead of a solid collider. This has the effect of disabling it - in that it won't cause other objects to stop or rebound if they hit it.

For example:

```
function Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X)) {
        collider.isTrigger = true;
    }
}
```

Note that things like `MouseOver` still work.

If you want to disable that completely, you can try `collider.enabled = false`. I'm not sure if that works or not. If it doesn't, you can always scale down your collider:

```
var myOldSize:Vector3;

function DisableBoxCollider(myCollider:BoxCollider)
{
    //actually just resizes it
    myOldSize=myCollider.size;
    myCollider.size=Vector3(0,0,0);
}

function EnableBoxCollider(myCollider:BoxCollider)
{
    if(myOldSize!=Vector3(0,0,0))
        myCollider.size=myOldSize;
}
```

You can use the above code to integrate it in your own project. I'm not going to spill out all of the code for you because else we'd miss the point of learning to program and post on Stackoverflow in general. But it should help you to get on your way. Try and play some with the code, and if you have questions, get back here and ask them, providing the question with some code to show what you have tried.

Comment: thanx for responding. Here what iam looking for is to run the function between trigger enter of one collider and trigger exit of another collider. Is it possible ?? here is the code           function OnTriggerEnter()            { if(other.gameObject.tag=="player"){  instantiate(enemy,transform.position,transform.rotation) } } now i want this instantiated enemy to die when the player exits the trigger of different collider. how to achieve this ??

Comment: Do you mean http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html and http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerExit.html ?